# PHPUnit with selenium

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use PHPUnit with selenium

I start the server
java -jar c:/xampp/selenium-server-standalone-2.18.0.jar

This is my test

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php';

class WebTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase {
  protected function setUp() {
    $this->setBrowser("*chrome");
    $this->setBrowserUrl("http://localhost/");
  }

  public function testMyTestCase() {
    $this->url('my/url/index.php');
    $link = $this->byId('1-m-0');
    $this->assertEquals('11', $link->text());
  }
}
```

Item with id="1-m-0" exists on page, but test fails cause it gets element as null.
I have tried with other elements, SeleniumTestCase class (with the same server) but not luck !

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, found it out. Here is my class now :

```
class WebTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase {
  protected function setUp() {
    $this->setBrowser("*firefox");
    $this->setBrowserUrl("http://localhost/");
  }

  public function testPlay() {
    $this->open('http://localhost/my/url/index.php');
    $this->waitForPageToLoad(4000);
    // Wait for ajax to load
    $this->waitForCondition("selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().$('#mytable').length > 0");
    $ids = array(
      '1-m-0',
      '2-n-1',
    );
    // Click ids
    foreach ($ids as $v) {
      $xpath = "xpath=//button[@id='{$v}']";
      $this->assertElementPresent($xpath);
      $this->click($xpath);
    }
  }
}
```

This article helped me:
http://devzone.zend.com/1014/acceptance-testing-of-web-applications-with-php/

I m using this selenium server: selenium-server-standalone-2.18.0.jar

Comment: waitForPageToLoad and waitForPageToLoad cause "BadMethodCallException: The command 'waitForPageToLoad' is not existent or not supported yet." What does it depend on?

Answer (score 0):

In case you find the phpunit library a little bit confusing we created a library that interacts with the Selenium Json Wire Protocol but we aimed to make it as similar as possible with the official documentation examples. So an example from  the selenium site in Java would have nearly the same syntax in php.

Check it out: https://github.com/Nearsoft/PHP-SeleniumClient

If you like it share it, get involved, fork it or do as you please :)

Regards, Mark.